# Are there any specific places where the bike spawns?

Tags: nether

Recently a bike has been added to Nether and I was wondering if there are some specific places where it spawns. Like for example some places just always spawn the same items. So I was wondering wether the bike would be on a

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are, this is a map that shows some of the spawns.  Of course people may have already taken them.

[image: Official Bike Map]
<sub>(source: [playnether.com](https://www.playnether.com/img/features-bike-map.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! While this does theoretically give the poster an answer to the question, we frown on link-only answers, as they, among other things, are prone to link rot. (See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/168476) for more information.) Please add some of the salient points from the link to your answer.

Comment: That is a link to an actual Nether map on the official game website so I don't see how this would be inappropriate.  I also don't think this downvote or the comment is necessary.  It is a game where there are spawns, as shown in the map, and I mentioned that there is the potential for them to be already taken.  There really isn't anything more which can be added.